# OpenLayers6 TileArcGISRest LAYERS param doesn't allow to modify and transparency of the features

Tags: openlayers, transparency-opacity

I am trying to modify the transparency of the features ans I don't have a clue about how to do it.

The site https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_TileArcGISRest.html refers to https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/export-map.htm and I don't know is it possible, I tried this:

```
params: {
  'layers':"show:3",
  'drawingInfo': "transparency: 50",
},
```

but transparency could be an attribute of the layer.

Any idea?

Comment: The ArcGIS server REST API (you showed) is for dynamic layers published by an ArcGIS Server - and not for tiled layers. Tiled layers already have all their visual elements cast in stone.

Comment: Use the opacity option in the layer https://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Tile-TileLayer.html

Comment: I tried opacity before, but I supose that I writed down in the wrong place, now in the layer it works! Thank you!